# How do I convert this Matlab code with meshgrid and arrays to Python code?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am attempting to write a program which constructs a matrix and performs a singular value decomposition on it. I am evaluating the function `ax^2 +bx + 1` on a grid. I then make a uniform meshgrid of `a` and `b`. The rows of the matrix correspond to different quadratic coefficients, while each column corresponds to a grid point at which the function is evaluated.

The matlab code is here:

```
% Collect data

x = linspace(-1,1,100);

[a,b] = meshgrid(0:0.1:1,0:0.1:1);

D=zeros(numel(x),numel(a));
sz = size(D)
% Build “Dose” matrix

for i=1:numel(a)

D(:,i) = a(i)*x.^2+b(i)*x+1;

end

% Do the SVD:

[U,S,V]=svd(D,'econ');

D_reconstructed = U*S*V';

plot(diag(S))
scatter3(a(:),b(:),V(:,1))
```

This is my attempt at a solution:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)

def f(x, a, b):
    return a*x*x + b*x + 1

a, b = np.mgrid[0:1:0.1,0:1:0.1]
#a = b = np.arange(0,1,0.01)

D = np.zeros((x.size, a.size))

for i in range(a.size):
    D[i] = a[i]*x*x +b[i]*x +1

U, S, V = np.linalg.svd(D)

plt.plot(np.diag(S))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")


ax.scatter(a, b, V[0])
```

but I always get broadcasting errors which I am not sure how to fix.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with:
for i in range(a.size):
    D[i] = a[i]*x*x +b[i]*x +1

but your problem is that a and b are 10,10 but D is 100,100 and x is 100,1.

Comment: x is 100x1 vector, while a is 10x10 matrix. Try x.shape, a.shape to check.

Comment: Hi Paula, I would like my D matrix to be an m x n matrix, where a is the number of a and b coefficients I have, and n is the number of x points I have. Each row corresponds to a distinct value of a, b, while each column corresponds to a gridpoint on which the quadratic is evaluated.

Why does it work in Matlab and not Python?

Comment: _but I always get broadcasting errors_ Please share the **entire** error message. Have you read the NumPy docs? That would be the logical place to start, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, in MATLAB you're assigning to `D(:,i)`, but in python you're assigning to `D[i]`. The latter is equivalent to `D[i, ...]` which is in your case `D[i, :]`. Instead you seem to need `D[:, i]`.

Secondly, in MATLAB using a linear index into a 2d array (namely `a` and `b`) will give you flattened views. If you do that with numpy you get slices of an array instead, just as I mentioned with `D[i]`.

You can do away with the loop with [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/theory.broadcasting.html#array-broadcasting-in-numpy) and getting your desired 2d array by `.ravel`ling (or reshaping) your `a` and `b` arrays:

```
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)[:, None]  # inject trailing singleton for broadcasting
a, b = np.mgrid[0:1:0.1, 0:1:0.1]
D = a.ravel() * x**2 + b.ravel() * x + 1
```

The way this works is that `x` has shape `(100, 1)` after we inject a trailing singleton (in MATLAB trailing singletons are implied, in numpy leading ones), and both `a.ravel()` and `b.ravel()` have shape `(10*10,)` which is compatible with `(1, 10*10)`, making broadcasting possible into shape `(100, 10*10)`. You could also replace the calls to `ravel` with

```
a, b = np.mgrid[...].reshape(2, -1)
```

which is a trick I sometimes use, but this is harder to read if you're unfamiliar with the pattern.

Side note: it's better to use example data where dimensions end up being of different size so that you notice if something ends up being transposed.

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't have thought to use `ravel`. One question, I seem to get slightly different elements in the `D` array in matlab and python. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @pythonraptor the reason is probably imprecision in floating-point arithmetic, and one likely source is the meshgrid/mgrid call. 0.1 is famously non-representable exactly (see e.g. `0.1 * 3 == 0.3` not being true with double precision), and there might be optimizations involved (such as [fused multiply-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fused_multiply-add)) that differ between the two implementations. Or perhaps `linspace` has similar differences. Or perhaps the _printing_ of the double values is different. Either way you'll get numerical differences in the `svd` phase the latest.

Comment: @pythonraptor oh yeah, and an important thing: in MATLAB linear indices go column by column, but in numpy linear indices go row by row. This might mean that you might have to use `a.T.ravel()` etc. to get the same order of items in `D` as in MATLAB. You can make sure by using different ranges for the two arguments in `mgrid`, preferably with different size as well, and compare those values with MATLAB. If your differences are on the order of machine precision (~1e-16) then it's fine.